# Unable to copy to a dir

Tags: directory

Any time I try to copy stuff over to the this folder it fails.

```
mslawson@Matts-Notebook:/tmp$ sudo cp -r rails_tutorial_sublime_text/* \~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/
cp: target `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/' is not a directory
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command,

```
sudo cp -r rails_tutorial_sublime_text/* ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/
```

or

```
sudo cp -Ri rails_tutorial_sublime_text/* ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/
```